# IF statement inside while loop woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, while-loop

I am trying to create a custom XML feed. I don't want while loop to output if stock quantity is 0. I have tried placing if statement inside while loop as well as outside like this:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() && 0 < $product->get_stock_quantity() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;
```

```
if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 ){
the actual while loop
}
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work. Any pointers on what I might be missing is much appreciated!

My full code:

```
header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>


<wine-searcher-datafeed>
<product-list>
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 999 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() && 0 < $product->get_stock_quantity() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
    ?>
    <row>
        <name><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?></name>
<description><?php $original = strip_tags($product->get_short_description());
        $stripped = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $original);
        echo $stripped; ?></description>
        <vintage><?php $code = $product->get_title();
echo preg_replace('/.*?(\d{4}).*/', '$1', $code); ?></vintage>
        <unit-size><?php the_field('stoerrelse'); ?></unit-size>
        <price><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></price>
        <url><?php echo $product->get_permalink(); ?></url>
        <min-order>1</min-order>
        <tax>Inc</tax>
        <offer-type/>
        <delivery-time>1-7 days</delivery-time>
        <stock-level><?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?></stock-level>

<?php rss_enclosure(); ?>
    <?php do_action('rss2_item'); ?>
    </row>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</product-list>
</wine-searcher-datafeed>
```

Comment: In your loop you are trying to access $product which is not defined in the current code. Here you can see example of using Woo queries where you can define stock quantity and loop only products with quantity - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Comment: Are you sure $product in while condition is available? Because, global product is after that while control structure. Also, global product is an object and it doesn't seem useful for you. Instead write condition inside loop. Create $product object as $product = wc_get_product( get_post_id ); and then use $product->get_stock_quantity();
Aslo to the condition should be < 1 not < 0

Comment: yeah the while condition works fine... Code is working. Only problem is that it outputs products out of stock.

Comment: Like i said use WC_Product_Query instead :)